# Diff Multiple Files and save the images of differences

Tags: linux, superuser

I am working on a linux platform. I have two revisions of same project. I want images of all the lines the files differ.

For lower number of files i had been listing all files with 'diff -qr dir1 dir2', taking the output to a text file and appending tkdiff or gvim -d at start of each line to get something like this:

```
tkdiff dir1/f1 dir2/f1
tkdiff dir1/f2 dir2/f2
tkdiff dir1/f3 dir2/f3
```

or

```
gvim -d dir1/f1 dir2/f1
gvim -d dir1/f2 dir2/f2
gvim -d dir1/f3 dir2/f3
```

I source the file and capture screenshot and save.

Is there a way to automate this process ?

Thank You

Comment: What part of the process do you think needs more automation?

Comment: @romainl I want to automate the part where i have to capture screenshots. Instead of moving to next difference and capturing each time. It would be better if i can capture all at once.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with Vim or diff. Better ask on superuser.

Comment: @romainl thanks! Updated the tags. I was hoping there would be some vim plugin's or command's which could help